# Has DI (dependency injection) been merged in Angular2 Alpha39?

Tags: dependency-injection, angular

I migrated from **Angular2 to Alpha39** from **Alpha37**. Now I get the error:

> GET http://localhost:8000/jspm_packages/npm/angular2@2.0.0-alpha.39/di.js 404 (Not Found)

The important statement I have in my code is:

```
import { Injector } from 'angular2/di';
```

Which module **di** is part of now? Should I not use the above import statement?

Comment: Try importing it from `angular2/angular2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it appears to be in angular2/angular2.